# How do I get an element inside a link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, element

I want to make a simulator that tells you the last comment of a specific username's profile on this website. I want to target a specific class or id from that link (the link being "https://scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant/"), and detect the simple text of the latest comment, and put it in a div or paragraph tag. For this statement, I want to state the about me text in the console. Here is what I have:

```
var link = "https://scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant/"
var aboutMe = link.getAttribute("editable read");
console.log(aboutMe);
```

The reason I have the getAttribute for "editable read" is because that's the name of the class I'm trying to get the text of. [The place where I'm trying to get the text/innerText of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8MpW.png)

Comment: Tell me something are you sending ajax request to get the html of this page? if yes a have solution for you.

Comment: Sorry, no. Just the class or id.

Comment: You have a different websie and you want to display last comment from this another website's  link, isn't it like that? That's what i understand

Comment: Sorry, but without **anything** to work with, there's no way of answering your question. Do you have any code so far that is supposed to do the job? If yes, please edit it into your answer.

Comment: Finished the changes.

Comment: @QaMarALi I realized what I was trying to accomplish. May I have help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the about of a user don't directly try and do it that way, use the scratch api.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(response["profile"]["bio"])
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hey again! Can you please show me what the code would be if I wanted to get any element on someone's profile on Github, or a recent comment?  Thanks!

Comment: @Orey I can help you if you make a new question

Comment: Okay, I will make one.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize I did. So sorry!